# Default value in ActiveDropDownList

Tags: php, jquery, yii

I've inherited a piece of code from an old developer and currently trying to figure out the method behind how it submits.

I'm currently trying to get a quick fix in place where I hide one of his fields to get the form submitting, the issue I'm having is that I can't seem to set the dropdownlist to a default value, which should be United Kingdom, with the id 826 in the database.

```
echo CHtml::ActiveDropDownList($address, 'country_id', CHtml::listData(Country::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name', 'continent'), array(
    'class' => 'col-md-5 hidden',
    'prompt' => 'Select Country',
    'label' => 'something here',
    'ajax' => array(
        'type' => 'POST',
        'url' => CController::createUrl('/user/UpdateRegions'),
        'dataType' => 'json',
        'data' => array('country_id' => 'js:this.value', 'YII_CSRF_TOKEN' => Yii::app()->request->csrfToken),
        'success' => 'function(data) {
                            $("#Address_country_region_id").html(data.country_id);
                            $("#Address_country_region_id").removeClass(\'hidden\');

                            if($("#venue_id").val() === "") {
                                $("#Address_country_region_id").addClass(\'hidden\');
                                }
                        }',
)));

$path = CController::createUrl('/admin/user/UpdateRegions');
$id = $address->id;
// On Load
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('ready', '
    $.ajax({
        type: \'POST\',
        dataType : \'json\',
        data: {\'country_id\': $(\'#Address_country_id\').val(), \'update_id\' : "' . $id . '"},
        url: "' . $path . '",
        success: function(data){
                    $(\'#Address_country_region_id\').html(data.country_id);
                }
    })
');
```

How do I get this dropdownlist pointing towards the country_id of 826 as the page loads so I can hide the field and pass the validation of the form.

regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this code you pasted does this:

the first part renders a dropdown which does an ajax request on change to /user/UpdateRegions to fill the dependent dropdown for the regions.

the second part does also an ajax request when the page is "ready". So that the region select is filled when the page is ready.

Your script should output the id 826 if you printout the current set id.
If not the value isn't correctly set to the address model.

```
echo $address->country_id;
```

If you want to set the default value you can do this at multiple places. e.g. in the controller 'before' the actual submitted value is set or in the model code itself (depends on your code e.g. if you have an additional form model which is extended from your activerecord model).

The correct line in your controller could be before something like this:

```
 $address->country_id= 826;
 before one of these lines in your controller

 $address->attributes=Yii::app()->request->getQuery(get_class($address));
 or 
 $address->attributes=Yii::app()->request->getPost(get_class($address));
 or 
 $address->attributes=$_POST['address']; // or $_GET
```

If you have difficulties to find the correct position post some controller code.

I guess you could find some help also here
[Yii 1.1: An Easy Solution for Dependent dropDownList Using AJAX](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/429/an-easy-solution-for-dependent-dropdownlist-using-ajax/)

Comment: Excellent answer, fills in gaps in my knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

To set default value for `$address` model, put

```
$address->country_id = Yii::app()->request->getParam(get_class($address).'[country_id]', 816);
```

before

```
echo CHtml::ActiveDropDownList($address, 'country_id', CHtml::listData(Country::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name', 'continent'), array(
```

Comment: this would destroy the possibility to set the country of the address model via post / get.

Comment: I've put an example about how set a default value for the country_id. Now the user can insert that code where he needs.

Comment: first his model is $address not $model ;)
second again his post / get submissions would then be lost. this is a dependend drop down what he wants. I am not sure if he wants to set the default id of the country or country region select

Comment: Hi, yes this answer works and the submissions will probably break but in this case the address etc are not important to the project and this is just a temporary fix until there is a few spare hours to rip out multiple models and controllers. I can't mark it as the correct question due to the fact it's pretty specific working towards my project but I have given a vote up.